# iPhone: how to decrease no. count on UILabel, when text enter in UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

when i am typing characters on **UITextField**, below the UITextField, i place the small UILable displaying 200, when **entering the characters** on UITextField the count has to decrease by one for each character and **displaying on UILabel**, can you suggest me, how to work on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your textField delegate:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    lblYourLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Characters: %d / 200",[textField.text length]];
    return YES;
}
```